# every moment of nature/ every moment of being in nature

Tags: word-request, sentence-request

I wanted to  advise somebody to enjoy every moment when they spend time in nature. How can I put it in words?

> 1)  my advice is to enjoy every moment in the nature
>
> 2) my advice is enjoy every moment of being in nature

Or Is there a better sentence for that?

Answer (score 1):

For something idiomatic in English, "in (the) nature" isn't going to work.

You could use:

> every moment **spent with nature**
>   every moment (spent) **in the natural world**
>   every moment (spent) **in the wild** *(this one is a little more specific)*

Those are all things I would consider natural. There's also the expression "getting back to nature", which wouldn't fit here, but is related.